# How to use function "get_data_structure"

Tags: r

I try to use the function "get_data_structure" but got an error as below.
Could anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you in advance

> get_data_structure("DUR_D")
> Error in data.frame(data_structure@concepts) :
> trying to get slot "concepts" from an object (class "data.frame") that is not an S4 object

Answer (score 3):

The problem appears to be a bug in the version of the `OECD` package on CRAN.  If you install the development version, it works.  First, close R and reopen a clean new session, then run this:

```
remotes::install_github("https://github.com/expersso/OECD")

library(OECD)
get_datasets()
get_data_structure("DUR_D")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I try to run as below but still not working: install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("expersso/OECD")
library(OECD)
get_datasets()
get_data_structure("DUR_D")

Comment: Please edit your question to include what you did and any other messages printed by R.  You need to do this in a clean R session, not your existing one.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in the package OECD 0.2.5.

It works with the package version 0.2.4 which you can install from CRAN's archived package section (https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/OECD).

If you want to access the archived package version directly in R, use the following code:

```
devtools::install_version("OECD", version = "0.2.4", repos = "https://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/")
```

Note that this requires the package 'devtools' to be installed.

Answer (score 1):

```
remotes::install_github("https://github.com/expersso/OECD")

library(OECD)    
dataset <- "DUR_D"
dstruc <- get_data_structure(dataset)
```

Try with `get_dataset("DUR_D")` i.e. without -s. as `get_datasets()` with `-s` will return a dataframe of available datasets.

Comment: I get the same error as with the original post.

Comment: Hi Rfanatic, thanks for your reply. I try your suggest, however, I still got the error